# Configure build flavors from file in Gradle

Tags: android, json, gradle, android-productflavors

I defined some product flavors in my *build.gradle*. For each variant I defined a task to update properties. In case of increase build variants count or adding new parameters to change, it may be difficult to manage these tasks. I created json like this

```
[{
    "server": "url1",
    "name": "name1",
    "language": "en"
},
{
    "server": "url2",
    "name": "name2",
    "language": "es"
}]
```

How can I use json file to configure my build fariants in cycle? Here is my current *build.gradle*:

```
    productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }
    flavor2 {
    }
    }


   tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
   if (task.name == 'generateFlavor1DebugBuildConfig') {
   task.dependsOn updateSettingsOnFlavor1Build
   }
   if (task.name == 'generateFlavor2DebugBuildConfig') {
   task.dependsOn updateSettingsOnFlavor2Build
   }

   task updateSettingsOnFlavor1Build << {
    ant.propertyfile(file: file('./src/main/assets/settings.properties')) {
      entry(key: "server", value: "myserver.com")
      entry(key: "name", value: "name1")
    }
   }
   task updateSettingsOnFlavor2Build << {
    ant.propertyfile(file: file('./src/main/assets/settings.properties')) {
      entry(key: "server", value: "myserver2.com")
      entry(key: "name", value: "name2")
    }
   }
```

Comment: Why would you want you?

Comment: @JaredBurrows to add new configurations with no effect on *build.gradle*

Comment: Well that is impossible right? How will you be able to assemble everything without calling `gradle assemble` to assemble all the product flavors each time?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Is it possible to create only one task, which reads properties from json and writes it to settings? My purpose is to avoid creating a stack of tasks

Comment: So instead of writing tasks you want to keep writing stuff in a json file?

Comment: @JaredBurrows that isn't such an alien concept, in that, this is exactly what the android DSL/plugin does. When you add a flavor, the plugin adds a bunch of tasks, configurations and sourcesets based on flavor name, all dynamically, all behind the scenes. (Not that this necessarily justifies what OP is trying to do.)

Comment: @RaGe Post an answer demonstrating your idea.